# Extract elements from list of httr headers

Tags: r, httr, magrittr

I have a simple question that has nonetheless stumped me.

I am trying to extract specific elements from a list of website headers for a set of given URLs. I have obtained the website headers using the `httr` package. Using `magrittr::extract`, I am able to successfully extract one element from the header for each URL and include this element in a tibble. However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to extract *more than one* element from the header for each URL.

For example, the below code helps me *successfully* extract the "status_code" for each URL and include it within a tibble. There is only one "status_code" for each URL.

```
pacman::p_load(httr, rvest, dplyr, purrr, tidyr)

some_urls <- c("https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=10",
               "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=4",
               "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=140",
               "https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=3"
)

df <- map_dfr(some_urls, ~{
    httr::GET(.x) %>% 
    magrittr::extract(c("url", "status_code"))
})
```

However, I am not interested in "status_code," but in "status." There may be MORE than one "status" for each URL. I am interested in extracting EVERY "status" for each URL and adding it to a tibble.

The below code does not work, because there is more than one "status" for each URL.

```
df <- map_dfr(some_urls, ~{
  httr::GET(.x) %>% 
  magrittr::extract(c("url", "status"))
})
```

This code gives me the following result:

```
Error:
! Column names `url`, `url`, and `url` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
  * "url" at locations 1, 2, 3, and 4.
Backtrace:
 1. purrr::map_dfr(...)
 2. dplyr::bind_rows(res, .id = .id)
 4. tibble:::as_tibble.list(dots)
 5. tibble:::lst_to_tibble(x, .rows, .name_repair, col_lengths(x))
 6. tibble:::set_repaired_names(x, repair_hint = TRUE, .name_repair)
 8. tibble:::repaired_names(= NULL)
 Error: 
Caused by error in `repaired_names()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
* "url" at locations 1, 2, 3, and 4.
```

I greatly appreciate any advice you may have! If inserting "name_repair" somewhere into my code is the answer, I have been unable to figure out how to successfully use this in my code. I have also tried setting column names in advance but seem to be unsuccessfully able to do this too. Please let me if you have any advice regarding how I can successfully extract this information!

Comment: What is `status` if it's not e.g. `403`?I cannot see anything else available in the object returned from `httr::GET("https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=3")`

Comment: @harre I'm basically trying to see if these pages redirect! E.g., some_urls[1] does not redirect. If I run `r <- httr::GET(some_urls[1], user_agent)` and 
`r$all_headers`, you can see that status is "200" for some_urls[1]. However, some_urls[3] does redirect.  If I run `r <- httr::GET(some_urls[3], user_agent)` and 
`r$all_headers`, I get a status as "302" (which indicates that the site has redirected) in addition to the status "200"

Comment: Please let me know if that clarifies what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may paste the multiple code into a single string - `all_headers` is a `list` which can vary in length from 1 to n.  If there are more elements, loop over the `all_headers` with `map`, `pluck` the 'status' from each of those elements and either `paste` (`toString`)

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(some_urls, ~{
    httr::GET(.x, user_agent) %>%
       {tibble(url = .$url,
               status = toString(unlist(map(.$all_headers, pluck, "status"))))}
    })
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  url                                                              status  
  <chr>                                                            <chr>   
1 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=10 200     
2 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=4  200     
3 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york           302, 200
4 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=3  200
```

or return a `list` and then `unnest` the list column later

```
library(tidyr)
map_dfr(some_urls, ~{
    httr::GET(.x, user_agent) %>%
       {tibble(url = .$url,
    status = map(.$all_headers, pluck, "status"))}
    }) %>% 
   unnest(status)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  url                                                              status
  <chr>                                                             <int>
1 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=10    200
2 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=4     200
3 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york              302
4 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york              200
5 https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/new-york/a?page=3     200
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! This works for me but it returns a result that all values of "status" are 403. What I'm trying to do is extract all values of status reported in all_headers for each URL. For example, if I run f I run `r <- httr::GET(some_urls[3], user_agent)` and then print `r$all_headers`, I can see multiple results for "status", including "302", "200", etc., rather than just "403". My question is ultimately how to get all of THESE statuses in a tibble, rather than just reports of "403." Please let me know if you can help!

Comment: @AnnaJones Just updated the post.  Sorry, I didn't earlier checked the structure correcly.  the `$` does partial matching and extracts the 'status_code' for 'status'.  We need to extract from the nested list `all_headers[[1]]$status`

Comment: @AnnaJones Do you have multiple elements of `all_headers` IN the example, i see a single list

Comment: @AnnaJones e.g. the str shows `$ all_headers:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 3
  .. .. ..$ status : int 403`

Comment: @AnnaJones your code givves only 403 i.e. `httr::GET(some_urls[3])$all_headers
[[1]]
[[1]]$status
[1] 403`.   and not the 302 or 200

Comment: Hi @akrun, thanks for your help! I just checked sorry and I think it only works and returns status as "302" and other values other than "403" when I include a user agent i.e.: `user_agent <- httr::user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36")
r <- httr::GET(some_urls[3], user_agent)
r$all_headers` . Beyond this, I am still not sure how to answer my question.... I will try to add a user_agent into your code and see if it works for me?

Comment: I just tried your code with the user_agent and can't seem to get it to work... but I do get the "302" and "200" codes rather than "403" when I run `httr::GET(some_urls[3], user_agent)$all_headers`! Please let me know if that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: @AnnaJones try the update

Comment: @AnnaJones the reason is as I mentioned earlier,  user_agent returns multiple elements for 'all_headers'.